# how to send standard output and standard error to two files

Tags: linux, rhel, logs, exec, standard

I use the following syntax in order to send standard output and standard error to $log file

```
log=/var/tmp/install.log
info=/tmp/info.log 

exec > $log 2>&1
```

how to redirect both standard output and standard error also to /tmp/info.log file ?

Comment: Since the two files will be identical, just link one to the other.

Comment: this not good option because the $log file will be deleted by some application and I need second backup file (  we must created redirect to second file because file $log will be deleted in the end of installation ) , so link cant help us

Comment: A hard link with `ln "$log" "$info"` will do. If one name is deleted, the data is still available under the other name.

Comment: I get -  ln  $log  /var/tmp/install.log
ln: failed to create hard link ‘ /var/tmp/install.log’ => ‘/tmp/inst.log’: Invalid cross-device link

Comment: Yes, both names have to be on the same filesystem for that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task is to preserve the log output even if an application deletes the log file.

By creating a second name for the log file with `ln`, the data in the log will be available under two names.  If one of the names is deleted, the data is still available under the other name.

In a script:

```
log=/var/tmp/install.log
info=/tmp/info.log 

ln -f "$log" "$info"

exec >"$log" 2>&1
```

If `$log` does not previously exist, you will need to create it with `touch "$log"` before the call to `ln`.

This assumes that both names reside on the same filesystem.

This answer does not assume that you're using `bash`. It will work with any `sh`-compatible shell.

Comment: should be    ln -f  execution $log  $info   ( log is the existing log file )

Comment: @yael I've fixed that now.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using bash, you can use process substitution and `tee`:

```
exec &> >(tee "$log" > "$info")
```

This will redirect both streams to the process substitution, where `tee` sends the output to `"$log"` and to stdin, which is redirected to `"$info"`.

Otherwise you'll probably have to start a background process that sends the contents of `/var/tmp/install.log` to `/tmp/info.log`:

```
log=/var/tmp/install.log
info=/tmp/info.log 
exec > "$log" 2>&1
tail -n+1 -f "$log" > "$info" &
```

`tail` will run in the background sending everything that comes to `/var/tmp/install.log` to `/tmp/info.log`.

Answer (score -1):

Just for completion's sake, you can write 1> as just > since the default file descriptor is the output. so 1> and > is the same thing.

So, command 2> error 1> output becomes, command 2> error > output